# How can I check webRTC datachannel compatibility using JavaScript in client side?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

WebRTC datachannel works only in Firefox nightly. How can I check it in client side?

Code is shown as follows;

```
if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x (ignoring remaining digits); 

 var ffversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number

 if (ffversion>=5)

  document.write("You're using FF 5.x or above")

 else if (ffversion>=4)

  document.write("You're using FF 4.x or above")

 else if (ffversion>=3)

  document.write("You're using FF 3.x or above")

 else if (ffversion>=2)

  document.write("You're using FF 2.x")

 else if (ffversion>=1)

  document.write("You're using FF 1.x")
}

else
 document.write("n/a")
```

Comment: I have heard it works in Chrome as well. Why don't you test for that?

Comment: Well there is no Demo to test it in Chrome Canary. Would be nice though if you provide me with the demo.. I was redirected from the HTML5 rock webRTC to use Mozilla. In either case, I need a JS to check the compatibility issues, so that I can start developing a prototype.

Comment: Then use feature detection, not UA String matching!!!

Comment: I used if (!window.RTCDataChannel)
document.write("error, browser doesn't support it")  .. But its not working allowing a error even though browser supports it !!

Comment: Maybe it's prefixed, just as the [`RTCPeerConnection`](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/js/adapter.js)?

Comment: There's a Chrome demo at [simpl.info/dc](http://www.simpl.info/dc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply test if the browser currently supports the features you're going to use. For example:

```
if (!window.mozRTCPeerConnection)
    // error, browser doesn't support it
```

If you're interested, here an interesting article: [Hello Chrome, it’s Firefox calling!](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/hello-chrome-its-firefox-calling/)

You basically can implement the same feature in Chrome just using `webkit` prefix instead of `moz`.

Comment: But it doesn't work for

if (!window.RTCDataChannel)
document.write("error, browser doesn't support it")

Comment: You create the data channel through the RTCPeerConnection, see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ and https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/bleeding-edge/by/comments/as/complete/ for example.

Comment: no! support RTCPeerConnection does not mean it also support for RTCDataChannel. You should try to test `window.RTCDataChannel` instead

Answer (score 5):

There's a Chrome `RTCDataChannel` demo now at [simpl.info/dc](http://www.simpl.info/rtcdatachannel).

This isn't very robust or complete, but you could create a `webkitRTCPeerConnection` object and then check if it has a `createDataChannel` member:

```
try { // or if (webkitRTCPeerConnection) {...}
  var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(null);
  if (pc && pc.createDataChannel) {
    var dc = pc.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel", {reliable: false});
    if (!!dc) {
      // doSomething()
    } 
  }
} catch (e) {
  // try some other instantiation 
}
```

Comment: I was going through your article, great job. But is there any demo for transfer within two chrome browsers. because the simpl.info/dc is within a single browser. I am not sure if they use any signalling ?

Comment: I know: there's no demo between two browsers yet :(. Working on it :). It should be possible to adapt the simpl.info/dc demo along the lines of apprtc.appspot.com (code at https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/#apprtc).

Comment: Thanks. I will wait to see it. Meanwhile I will try to follow your steps and learn. So, is there any example on data transfer like chat ?

Comment: Well figured out easyrtc. And it works in Moz ... www.easyrtc.com

Comment: Also https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/chat-hangout -- I haven't managed to get it to work, but that may just be me! There's also a file transfer demo at http://filetransfer.jstroem.com.

Comment: And unfortunately the later also gets stuck in 0% . Did the second worked for you ?

Comment: First link should be http://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/chat-hangout/ (needs the trailing slash). Second works for me.

Comment: For 2nd: Does it have any filesize limit? And any github page to check. As console have no log messages.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **webrtcsupport** package. It seems to be cross-browser (Chrome & FF). 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/webrtcsupport

If you don't wanna use the NPM package, the main logic can be found here. 
https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/webrtcsupport/blob/master/index-browser.js

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript

```
var prefix;
var version;
if (window.mozRTCPeerConnection || navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
  prefix = 'moz';
  version = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([0-9]+)\./)[1], 10);
} else if (window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
  prefix = 'webkit';
  version = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)/) && parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./)[2], 10);
}

if(prefix == 'moz' || prefix == 'webkit' && version > 41){
  console.log("Browser Support WebRTC")
} else {
  console.log("This Browser Not Support WebRTC")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is not right.

```
if (window.RTCDataChannel) {
    // the browser support dataChannel
} else {
   // the browser does not support dataChannel
}
```

If browser support RTCPeerConnection, it not means also support for RTCDataChannel。Such as Edge, `createDataChannel` on instance of `RTCPeerConnection` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one mentions checking the prototype.

You can check if createDataChannel exists by doing this:

```
if (!window.RTCPeerConnection.prototype.createDataChannel) {
    // Data Channels not supported
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out. Thanks for all your help.
http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/

Comment: Actually, `detect.js` is not doing what you want: it's just a browser sniffing – that in web development is not used anymore. So you don't detect the support of webRTC. This check is made at line 53 in view-source:http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/, and it has exactly the same check I posted before.

Answer (score 0):

Another package that checks for WebRTC support is DetectRTC https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC