# Detect of browser for specific functionality support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not able to detect browser, I want to show this as warning  (this is a verse from http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/)

```
    <h3 id="gum" style="color: red; display: none;">
    mozGetUserMedia is missing, do you have the latest
    <a href="http://nightly.mozilla.org/">Nightly</a> and set
    <i>media.navigator.enabled</i> to true?
    </h3>
<script>
 if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || !navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
    document.getElementById("gum").style.display = "block";}
</script>
```

This was discussed in [How can I check webRTC datachannel compatibility using JavaScript in client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774386/how-can-i-check-webrtc-datachannel-compatibility-using-javascript-in-client-side) but not supporting both navigator.webkit and moz , how should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( !( navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia ) ) {
    // getUserMedia is not supported
}
```

Adapted from [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Or

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if ( !navigator.getUserMedia ) {
    // getUserMedia is not supported
}
```

Re comment:

```
var browser = BrowserDetect.browser,
    version = parseInt( BrowserDetect.version, 10 );

if ( !( browser == 'Chrome' && version > 25 ||
     browser == "Firefox" && version > 18 ) ) {
     // do stuff
}
```

Feature detection is preferable to browser sniffing.

Comment: Thanks and if I want to do the below for firefox like combining:
        
        if (BrowserDetect.browser != "Chrome" ||
        parseInt(BrowserDetect.version,10) < 26) {
        $("#version").show(); }

        if (BrowserDetect.browser != "Firefox" ||
        parseInt(BrowserDetect.version,10) < 19) {
        $("#version").show(); }

Comment: It doesn't work. Somehow it ignores. I also tried with jquery. 

         if ( !( browser == 'Chrome' && version > 25 ||
     browser == "Firefox" && version > 18 ) ){
        $("#version").show(); }

Comment: @Learningtocode. Chrome stable is currently v25, beta is v26. So change to e.g. `browser == 'Chrome' && version > 24`. BTW no need to `parseInt` `BrowserDetect.version`.

Comment: @Learningtocode. Please explain "It doesn't work" - or better, ask your first comment as a new question.